# Display all nodes posted on a certain month and day between 1990 and 2014

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I want to display all nodes created on lets say, March 30 (between 1990 to 2014). Views contextual filters seems to display nodes posted on March 30 this year, how do i make the contextual filters include content posted on March 30 between lets say 1990 till 2014?

Answer (score 1):

The custom module method is:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(db_query("SELECT nid
    FROM node
    WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = 3 AND DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = 30 AND
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) BETWEEN 1990 AND 2014")->fetchCol());
```

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible using the views UI so you would have to use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) to get this working using views.